# How could I manage memory in objective C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I am not familiar with objective c++, and here is my question: suppose I have a class

```
class MyTestClass
{
 public:
  int memLength_;
  char *mem;
  MyTestClass(int memLength)
  {
      memLength_ = memLength;
      mem = new char[memLength_];
   }
   ~MyTestClass()
   {
      delete []mem;
   }

}
```

Now what I want to do is to create a `MyTestClass` object using Objective C++, and what I did is as follows:

```
@interface ObjectRetriever : NSObject
+ (MyTestClass)ObtainMyTestClass;  // Function 1
+ (MyTestClass*)ObtainMyNextTestClass; //Function 2
@end

+(MyTestClass)ObtainMyTestClass
{

  int memLen = 100;

  MyTestClass myClass(memLen)
  return myClass;

}
+ (MyTestClass*)ObtainMyNextTestClass
{

  MyTestClass *myClassPtr;
  myClassPtr = new MyTestClass(memLen)
  return myClassPtr;
}
```

So when I use the `ObjectRetriever` to create `MyTestClass` object, I will do in this way

```
 MyTestClass testClassObject1 = [ObjectRetriever ObtainMyTestClass];
  MyTestClass *testClassObjectPtr2 = [ObjectRetriever  ObtainMyNextTestClass];
```

My questions then are as follows:

- `ObtainMyTestClass` and `ObtainMyNextTestClass`, which one is better?
- If I implement and use the class in this way, will I have the danger of memory leak?

Thanks.

Comment: "The operator that uses the class"?!? You mean the "constructor"?

Comment: Did you consider using [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) ?

Comment: @KerrekSB Here I mean the user that uses the class

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, and I am using C++11

Comment: What value does the class add if it doesn't own the memory? There is no encapsulation here. Might be worth rethinking the design. Your factory methods shouldn't be creating data members; that's what the constructor is for.

Comment: @gavinb Thanks, your comments make sense, and I have reorganised the question.

Comment: having a member like char *mem; that you allocate in your class can cause problems for you regarding ownership if you do not carefully design your class (e.g. having a copy constructor). It is better to use a smart pointer shared_ptr to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

First, the short answers to your specific questions

> If I implement and use the class in this way, will I have the danger of memory leak?

Yes. If you do not delete[] the int array in the future, it will be lost. Also, in the second (pointer) implementation you could additionally lose the MyTestClass instance.

> ObtainMyTestClass and ObtainMyNextTestClass, which one is better?

ObtainMyTestClass, because there's no danger to lose a MyTestClass instance.

Now the long part. The main problem is that it is not clear to me what you really want. The question title suggests you want to cleanly manage (i.e. retain/release) your data. However, in the description you state the data is managed manually by the user of your class and you want it this way. Then, in your code examples you try do a mixture of both (array newing is done automatically by ObjectRetriever, array deletion is up to the user). So, here are my   suggestions:

a) If you want the memory management to be up to the user, you don't need an Objective-C Wrapper class. As you are using Objective-C++ you can use the MyTestClass exactly the same as in C++, like in your 2nd code block.

b) If you want safe memory management, and you cannot or don't want to change MyTestClass, I suggest to wrap the creation and deletion of the int array in the init and dealloc of an ObjC Object. This should work with or without ARC.

```
    @interface TestClassWrapper :NSObject{
      int* array;
    }
    -(MyTestClass) getTestClass;
    @end

    @implementation TestClassWrapper
    -(id)init{
      if(![super init])return nil; 
      array=new int[100];
      return self;
    }
    -(void)dealloc{
      delete[] array;  
      [super dealloc];
    }
    -(MyTestClass)getTestClass{
      return MyTestClass(100,array);
    }

   }
   @end
```

c) If you want safe memory management, and you can and want to change MyTestClass, I suggest to rewrite MyTestClass as not to require extern memory management.

Comment: Thanks, and it is very clear for me now. Based on your c) suggestion, I decide to let MyTestClass to manager the memory by itself. If I do that, could you answer my two questions?

Comment: With your modification, the question boils down to whether use objects on the stack or on the heap. Well, this depends on the semantic of MyTestClass and the intention of your program (e.g.: Does the copy constructor of MyTestClass deep-copy the data, or does it just copy the pointer to the data?). In a non-memory-managed environment as c++ I tend to prefer stack objects since you can never forget a delete. As you are using cxx11 you might look also at std::shared_pointer. Be aware that in any case you might need careful implementation of copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator.